# How to read "std::greater<>{}" in "std::make_heap"

Tags: c++, comparison, stdvector, heap

```
// min heap solution
// extract k smallest data from a min-heap of all n data points
class K_Smallest_MinHeap {

public:

  K_Smallest_MinHeap(std::size_t n, std::size_t k): N(n), K(k), count(0)
    {  }

  void add(int value){
    values.push_back(value);
  }
  
  std::vector<int> get(){
    std::make_heap(values.begin(), values.end(), std::greater<>{});
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < K; ++i){
      std::pop_heap(values.begin(), values.end(), std::greater<>{});
      result.push_back(values.back());
      values.pop_back();
    }
    return result;
  }
  
private:
  std::size_t N;
  std::size_t K;
  std::size_t count;
  std::vector<int> values;
};
```

Hi everyone

I do not understand the "std::greater<>{}" in std::make_heap()

I thought the takes only two iterators begin&end?

"void make_heap( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );"

Thank you for helping!

Comment: There are multiple overloads of that function. [See (2) here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap).

Comment: Optional compare. The default is `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap):

```cpp
template< class RandomIt >
void make_heap( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );

template< class RandomIt >
constexpr void make_heap( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );

template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void make_heap( RandomIt first, RandomIt last,
                Compare comp );

template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
constexpr void make_heap( RandomIt first, RandomIt last,
                          Compare comp );
```

Constructs a `max heap` in the range `[first, last)`. The first version of the function uses `operator<` to compare the elements, the second uses the given comparison function comp.

> I do not understand the "std::greater<>{}" in std::make_heap()

> I thought the takes only two iterators begin&end?

If your `make_heap` function only take two iterators, it will create a `max_heap`.

If you want to create a `min_heap`, you should use `operator>` to compare the elements, this is exactly what `std::greater<>{}` does.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes sense and helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The function `std::make_heap` is overloaded for two sets of parameters

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
void make_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);

template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
void make_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
Compare comp);
```

So the third parameter specifies explicitly the comparison function used to build a heap.

Comment: Thank you. This way I specify if it's min or max heap?

Comment: @YvesSchilli You are right. The comparison function can be of any complexity. For example you could define it such a way that all even numbers will be less (or greater) than all odd numbers.